# How to run .msi file in linux? (Ubuntu in my case)

Tags: 20.04, file-type

I've been trying to run a .msi file in ubuntu. From what I've read, the .msi file can run on Windows natively, however, is it possible to run the .msi file in Linux(Ubuntu in my case)?

Comment: .msi files are for Windows, not Ubuntu.

Comment: MSI = *MicroSoft Installer*.   Ask the creator (microsoft) to create them for non-microsoft products.

Comment: What is the program you wanted to run? Most likely an alternative is available for Ubuntu, and we can suggest it.